# Failed to ping external network from linux namespace, why?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I created a namespace, and used a veth pair(veth1 and veth2) to connect the namespace with my host. I also created a linux bridge in my host and add eth0 and veth1 to the bridge as interfaces. Hers is the commands:

```
ip netns add namespace2
ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth2
ip link set veth2 netns namespace2
brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br1 ens33
ifconfig ens33 0.0.0.0
ifconfig br1 192.168.90.43/22 up
brctl addif br1 veth1
ip netns exec namespace2 ifconfig veth2 192.168.90.47/22 up
ip netns exec namespace2 route add default gw 192.168.91.254
iptables -t filter  -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in ens33 --physdev-out veth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter  -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out ens33 --physdev-in veth1 -j ACCEPT
```

When I ping outside from my host, it works

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

But when I ping from my namespace, it fails

```
ip netns exec namespace2 ping 8.8.8.8
```

I try to ping my gateway from

```
ip netns exec namespace2 ping 192.168.91.254
```

It has about 70% package loss.

Why it that happen?

Comment: Well I wrote an answer telling you forgot to bring `veth1` up. But then I read about 70% packet loss (when it should have been 100%). So I'm at a loss and deleted the answer

Comment: Eventually I found it's about arp for the ip - arp binding was wrong, but I don`t know why it would be wrong.